Why the split mass geometry trick to solve for ratios works in these problems?
I have an idea about "why" this center of mass trick OR mass point trick to solve for ratios in problems like this works
here suppose we are given any two ratios let the given ratios  be AF:FB and BD:DC and we are asked to solve for all other ratios. Now what we do is assume some masses at the vertices A,B and C such that the center of mass(C.O.M) of A,B and C lies at point P and for this the C.O.M of A and B should be at F and C.O.M of B and C should be at D and C.O.M of A and C at E because in this way, the center of mass of A,B and C will surely lie at their intersection point P and then we can easily solve for all other ratios. But in problem like this one 
We say that the mass 10 unit at C is for line segment AC and 9 unit mass at C is for line segment BC but to solve for  CO:OF we combine the mass at point C and say that its 19 units why? It doesn't make any sense because if mass at vertex C is 19 units then neither E nor D would remain the C.O.M of C,A and C,B respectively. so when it comes to segment CF we are combining the masses at C but for all other segments we are treating them separately why?
P.S- I don't have a strong mathematical background(just have some knowledge about high school physics and mathematics) so it would be appreciated if you use simple/basic mathematics to explain this and lay more emphasis on the physics perspective or the essence.

Sorry, I don't understand what is given in the second problem and what is asked. All I see is a triangle with some lines, I assume that the numbers along the edges are lengths, but I have no idea what 21F means and so on.

you don't know about the C.O.M trick to solve these kind of problems? this 21 here represents C.O.M of masses at vertex A and B which are taken 15units and 6units here and the numbers along with lengths are "ratios" in which that length is divided have a look at this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_point_geometry.

There's no need to be condescending. Not everyone knows everything and the picture is obviously a little unclear without further clarifications.

@HackR I was just asking him,  didn't mean to sound "superior" or "intellectual". I apologize if it came out that way.

Many of us understand the use of masses on polygons both as toy problem scenarios and as actual calculations for physical properties of objects. What Andrei is saying is that your post is not clear: we cannot tell what the starting information is and what must be determined. I suggest revising the post.

@RobinSparrow my post is not about any particular problem. I am just asking why this "splitting of mass" method works? why do we combine the masses when it comes to finding ratio of cevians  but split the masses when it comes to finding other ratios? what's going on here?

Here are some words about the given situation, trying to explain the framework (as close as possible to physics), and why "it works". Let us start with the following situation. In some points $A,B,C,\dots$ there are some "masses" $s,t,u,\dots$ . Where is the "center of mass of the system"?
Here are some ways to see the situation.

We are in the affine plane and consider $A,B,C$ as points. The affine plane is not coming with a chosen cartesian system of coordinates, but we try to do something (not depending on any human / observer choice). We make a choice of a point $O$, named origin, or observation point. An other observer will also take her point, $\Omega$. Things should be the same as seen from $O$ and/or $\Omega$. Now we can define vectors to identify points in the space. We can scale vectors, and for this we need only the geometry of the line, and assume that each line can be parametrized with numbers. So $\overrightarrow{OA}$ is a vector, we consider on the line $OA$ (for a short time) a point we call "one", so we have a signed distance from $O$ to $A$ on this line, and given a scalar $\lambda$ we can multiply this distance with $\lambda$, obtain an other number, and see where it lives on the line. This point is called, say $A'$, and so we also define the scalar multiplication, $\lambda\overrightarrow{OA}=\overrightarrow{OA'}$. We can also use the geometry of the given plane, assume that there is a suitable notion of parallelism, and can thus draw parallelograms. Using this geometric construction we can define the sum of two vectors based in $O$. Given the vectors $\overrightarrow{OA}$, $\overrightarrow{OB}$ we define the sum vector $\overrightarrow{OS}:=\overrightarrow{OA}+\overrightarrow{OB}$ to have $S$ in the plane exactly at the place making $OASB$ a parallelogram. OK, now we have the mathematical scene to do "the same" as in physics, or rather support the physical understanding of the world by a mathematical mechanism. It turns out that the choice of the "one" on the line $OA$ is not making the construction dependent on the choice. Note that the sum above determining $S$ changes dramatically when we change $O$ to $\Omega$.

But what is kept in place when changing the observer is a weighted sum with a total of the weights equal to one, like...
$$
\begin{aligned}
\overrightarrow{OF} &= \frac s{s+t}\overrightarrow{OA} +\frac t{s+t}\overrightarrow{OB}\ ,
\\
\overrightarrow{OP} &= \frac s{s+t+u}\overrightarrow{OA} 
 +\frac t{s+t+u}\overrightarrow{OB}
 +\frac u{s+t+u}\overrightarrow{OC}\ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
and the points $F,P$ are uniquely defined and the same for both the $O$-observer and the $\Omega$-observer. They correspond to the posted picture, and in it there is on $O$ or $\Omega$ explicitly isolated. We are working in an affine (geometry) context.

Sometimes mathematicians go even further and write instead of the above simply
$$
\begin{aligned}
F &= \frac s{s+t}A +\frac t{s+t}B\ ,
\\
P &= \frac s{s+t+u}A 
 +\frac t{s+t+u}B
 +\frac u{s+t+u}C\ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
and still claim there is an affine world underlying the situation. If this is too complicated, but must be introduced in the school, mathematicians have invented a way to work with these objects "algebraically" (or vectorially) in the following manner: Just "think" instead that $A,B,C$ are elements of a vector space like $\Bbb R^n$. In the plane these are either two coordinates tuples or complex numbers depending on the preferences. The algebraic formalism also works. (But is for the purists not needed, the origin $O$ is chosen for instance "without need"...) The scalars involved in writing $P$ as a weighted sum with total weight one are called "barycentric coordinates", and there is a fruitful application for them in the geometry of the triangle (in elementary geometry). The point $P$ from the last relation is the center of mass, the centroid of the "system" $A,B,C$, with masses equal to $s,t,u$ placed in $A,B,C$. For more points similar weighted sums are easily written. (If $u=0$ we obtain the formula for $F$.)

Now we come closer to the question. Observe that (at least algebraically) we can regroup:
$$
\begin{aligned}
F &= \frac s{s+t}A +\frac t{s+t}B\ ,
\\
P &= \frac s{s+t+u}A 
 +\frac t{s+t+u}B
 +\frac u{s+t+u}C
\\
&=
\frac{s+t}{s+t+u}
\underbrace{
\left(
\frac s{s+t}A +\frac t{s+t}B
\right)}_{=F}
+\frac u{(s+t)+u}C
\ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
and can give the following physical meaning to the last relation.
Consider masses $s,t,u$ in $A,B,C$.
We use the notation $(A,B,C;s,t,u)$ for this "system".
We can thus replace the "subsystem" $(A,B;s,t)$ by $(F,s+t)$, and the center of mass is the same for $(A,B,C;s,t,u)$ and $(F,C;s+t,u)$.

A word on the used notation. Above i am writing something like $(A,B,C;15,6,19)$ for the system with points $A,B,C$ and masses $15,6,19$ in these points. The notation in the picture is something like $15A + 6B + 19C$, which i consider to be misleading for the present purposes, especially when we replace $19C$ by $10C + 9C$ written as $10C|9C$. Why do i consider notations like $15A+\dots $ misleading? Because they suggest a multiplication of an object like $A$ or related to $A$ with a scalar, fifteen. In fact, we have three unnormed scalars in the example $(A,B,C;15,6,19)$, and the right notation for the "total point" is
$\displaystyle\left(\ 
\frac {15}{15+6+19}A+ 
\frac {6}{15+6+19}B+ 
\frac {19}{15+6+19}C\ ,\ 15+6+19\ \right)$, and yes, the component with the masses is obtained by a simple addition, but in the component with the points we have to use "normed" weights, their sum must be one. Above, the coefficient of $A$ is not $15$, as the notation suggests it, but rather $15/40$, its normed version.

By symmetry, we have the same center of mass for $(F,C;s+t,u)$, for $(E,B;s+u,t)$, and for $(D,A;t+u,s)$. Namely the center of mass of the system $(A,B,C;s,t,u)$.

Observe that we can not only "aggregate" a subsystem, but we can also "disaggregate", for instance - see also the OP picture (from a wiki-page, mass point geometry) - that placement of masses in $C$, symbolized by $10C|9C$ in the picture, we can pass from $(A,B,C; 15,6,19)$ to $(A,B,C,C;15,6,10,9)$ back and forth.

In physics, if we have two points with masses $s,t$, the mass center point is on the line determined by the points, between them, at parts of lengths inverse proportional to the masses. (The bigger the mass, the closer the point to the mass center.) The accent falls here on the line connecting the point. If we have three points with masses $s,t,u$, the mass center point is in the plane determined by them (at a position with barycentric coordinates $[s:t:u]$), and so on. For this reason, the "trick works" when dealing with figures like the one in the first posted picture. And it supports the theorem of Ceva for this configuration.

Let us see now how / why the "physical" or "mechanical" solution works mathematically. When we consider in a system of points with masses a subsystem
(or more subsystems), we may use the same notation, but insert further parantheses. For instance, starting with $(A,B,C;15,6,19)$ we may consider a subsystem,  only the $B,C$ points, inside it. Then the notation $(A,(B,C);15,(6,19))$ tells us to consider (and then aggregate) $B,C$ to an equivalent system. Here, equivalent means "with the same mass center point, and same mass". We denote this equivalence between systems by $\sim$.

Let us see how the method works in the given situation, which is Problem Two on the already mentioned wiki page, same as the second OP problem. We have the chain of equivalences:
$$
\begin{aligned}
(A,C;15,10)&\sim(E;25)\ ,\\
(B,C;6,9)&\sim(D;15)\ ,\\
(D,E;15,25)&\sim(0;40)\ ,\\[2mm]
(A,C,B,C;15,10,6,9)
&\sim((A,C),(B,C);(15,10),((6,9))\sim(E,D;25,15)\sim(O;40)\\
&%\sim(A,B,C,C;15,6,10,9)
\sim(A,B,(C,C);15,6,(10,9))
\sim(A,B,C;15,6,19)
\\
&\sim((A,B),C;(15,6),19)\sim(F,C;21,19)\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
Why do we combine for the one purpose, do not combine for the other purpose the masses in $C$? Because we do so (at an intermediate step), and because doing so we obtain the position of $O$ on the segment $CF$, respectively on the segment $DE$. Explicitly, extracting one equivalence from the last chain of equivalences:

The relation $(O,40)\sim(F,C;21,19)$ tells us where is $O$ on the line, on the segment $CF$.
The relation $(O,40)\sim(E,D;25,15)$ tells us where is $O$ on the line, on the segment $DE$.
Note that $O$ is in fact defined to be $O=DE\cap CF$, but we know (by construction and choice of weights, and the properties of grouping subsystems and passing to equivalent systems) it must be the mass center point of the whole system.



